# sikuli: how to execute java jar file

Tags: java, jar, execute, sikuli

I loaded a java jar file into http://www.sikuli.org/ and tried to run it like this but it is not working. Any hints?

```
load("C:\Users\...\TJF.jar")

import subprocess
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'TJF.jar'])
```

Error message: Unable to access jarfile TJF.jar

Comment: No idea what sikuli is, but looks like java is unable to access TJF.jar, perhaps specifying path to the jar will help (in call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment was correct. Full path necessary. No "load" line necessary.